# Is i=i+1 an undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, increment, undefined-behavior

I'm using codeblocks and it is giving a different output to other compilers and I can't find a solution to it.What's the undefined behaviour in this program and is there any solution to avoid it?

This is the code to print the nth number in a number system with only 3 & 4.

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                              
#include<math.h>                                                               
int main(void)                                                                 
{                                                                              
    int n,i,value;                                                             
    scanf("%d",&n);                                                            
    value=i=0;                                                                 
    while(n>0)                                                                 
    {                                                                          
        if((n%2)==0)                                                           
        {                                                                      
            value+=4*pow(10,i);                                                
        }                                                                      
        else                                                                   
        {                                                                      
            value+=3*pow(10,i);                                                
        }                                                                      
        n=(n-1)/2;                                                             
        i=i+1;                                                                 
    }
printf("\nThe number is : %d",value);                                                                          
}
```

It works fine for numbers upto 6..And the output for numbers greater than 6 is one less than what it actually should be. E.g. if n=7,output=332 where it should be 333.

EDIT : Provided the full code with braces.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title really depends on the language, how it's designed and specified. But in general, `i = i + 1` is a well-defined operation.

Comment: As for your problem, it looks like some C code, and in C indentation is not significant, which means the code in the `else` part in the shown snippet is only the assignment to `value` and the other two statements are outside the `else`.

Comment: Always use braces! Unless you want to work at Apple, that is.

Comment: provide the actual code!!

Comment: Edited the post with the actual code

Comment: Also hint, 'double pow(double x, double y)'

Comment: instead of computing the power using floating point operations, why not set a variable int pow10 = 1; at the start and then multiply it by 10 each time? pow10 *= 10;

Comment: when wanting the user to input some value.  output a prompt letting the user know exactly what is expected for input..  Otherwise the user is left staring at a blinking cursor and no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no undefined behavior in this code. `i=i+1;` is well-defined behavior, not to be confused with `i=i++;` which gives undefined behavior.

The only thing that could cause different outputs here would be [floating point inaccuracy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Try `value += 4 * (int)nearbyint(pow(10,i));` and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

you're using the function pow(), which has the signature

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

and calculations as int. Rounding/truncation errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that floating point gets truncated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a compiler bug.
You are computing the result as `value+=3*pow(10,i);` but what this actually translates to is value+= (int)(3*pow(10,i));

One of two things might be wrong here:

1. **pow(10,0)!=1.0**
2. cast to int is truncating the result incorrectly.

To debug it easily just try printing the partial results and see there the  problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is most likely that the `pow` function on this particular platform performs its computations by taking the log of the argument (perhaps natural log; perhaps log base 2), multiplying by the exponent, and then raising the base of the first logarithm to the power of that product.  Performing such an operation with infinite-precision numbers would yield a mathematically-correct result, as would performing the operation on extended-precision numbers and returning a `double` result.  My guess would be that the `pow` function used on this implementation may have been written for a platform which could perform the intermediate computations using extended-precision numbers, and which would consequently return correct double-precision values, but it is being run on a platform which lacks an extended-precision type.  As a consequence of this, `pow(10,3)` may be returning something like 999.9999999997, and coercing that to `int` yields 999 rather than 1000.

If you're trying to get an integer-type result, there's really no reason to compute the power as a floating-point value.  Rather than computing 10^i within the loop, it would be better to have a variable that's initialized to 1 and gets multiplied by 10 each time through the loop.